# Identify and delete duplicate values in single row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of 30,000 lines . I need to find out duplicate values in multiple columns but in the same rows. For example

```
Row 1:     1234       5678       2345     7586   1234    2345
```

I have 30,000 similar rows.

I need to identify and then delete duplicate values, so in this case for example, I need to keep only one entry of 1234 and 2345 and delete the duplicate entries.

How to do this?

Comment: http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-in-excel/

Comment: Is each value in a different column or is the entire string in a single cell on each row?  Can there be more than one duplicate of a specific value in a row?  Do you always want to keep the first entry and delete the subsequent duplicates?  Do you want to "delete in place" (leave holes where a duplicate was removed), or consolidate the remaining values?

Comment: @DavidPostill - it looks like that proposed duplicate focuses on duplicate records.  This question is about duplicate items within a record, which those solutions don't work for.

Comment: So what you mean is if cells in the **same row** are duplicates, keep only one? Do this **separately for every row**? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Max does every row have the same number of entries? If not, what's the max number of entries on a single row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper columns. For the example you gave, use this formula for `G1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

... and then copy that into `H1:L1`. If your rows don't all have the same number of records, you can change the formula to address any blank cells:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)=1,A1,""))
```

---

An alternative VBA approach would be:

```
Option Explicit
Function RemoveDuplicatesInRows(dataRange As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim s As String
    For r = 1 To dataRange.Rows.Count
        s = ""
        For c = 1 To dataRange.Columns.Count
            If InStr(1, s, "|" & dataRange.Cells(r, c).Value & "|") > 0 Then
                dataRange.Cells(r, c).Value = ""
            Else
                s = s & "|" & dataRange.Cells(r, c).Value & "|"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

...which can called somewhere else in VBA with something like this:

```
RemoveDuplicatesInRows Sheet1.Range("A1:F30")
```